# Insertar dato con iteracion en php

Tags: php, html

Tengo en el modelo la siguiente función que quiero introducir en la base de datos:

```
public function agregarBolsasModel($datos, $tabla){
         $stmt = Conexion::conectar() -> prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla(lote, caja, bolsa)VALUES(:uno1, :dos2, :tres3)");
         $stmt -> bindParam(":uno1", $datos["loteNum"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
         $stmt -> bindParam(":dos2", $datos["cajaNum"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
         $stmt -> bindParam(":tres3", $datos["valoresBox"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
         if($stmt->execute()){

            return "ok";
         }else{
             return "error";
         }
         $stmt->close();
    }
```

La cuestion que el tercer el valor o ":tres3" es un arreglo de datos que paso con el siguiente array:(Pasa a un controlador, pero aqui lo omito)

```
 public function agregarEnCaja(){
       $datos = array("loteNum" => $this -> loteIngreso, //101
                      "cajaNum"=> $this -> cajaIngreso,  //1
                      "valoresBox"=> $this -> valoresCaja); //[1,2,3]
        $respuesta=$respuesta=GestorOIT::agregarBolsasController($datos);
        echo $respuesta;
   }
```

Como puedo hacer para iterar el elemnento 3 con el fin de que me introduzca los datos dependiendo de su tamaño, ejemplo, el array datos es asi:

```
$datos={loteNum:101, cajaNum:1, valoresBox[1,2,3]}
```

quiero que quede en la función asi, dependiendo de su tamaño:

```
INSERT INTO tabla(lote, caja, bolsa)VALUES(101,1,1);
INSERT INTO tabla(lote, caja, bolsa)VALUES(101,1,2);
INSERT INTO tabla(lote, caja, bolsa)VALUES(101,1,3);
```

Cualquier ayuda se agradeceria un monton.

**EDITADO**

Intente de esta manera pero nada

```
public function agregarBolsasModel($datos, $tabla){
        $datosL=array($datos["valoresBox"]);
        for($p=0; $p<sizeof($datosL); $p++){
            $stmt = Conexion::conectar() -> prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla(lote, caja, bolsa)VALUES(:uno1, :dos2, :tres3)");
            $stmt -> bindParam(":uno1", $datos["loteNum"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt -> bindParam(":dos2", $datos["cajaNum"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt -> bindParam(":tres3", $datosL[$p], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();
        }

          $stmt->close();
 }
```

Comment: ¿Cómo no funciona lo que intentaste? ¿Recibes algún mensaje de error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo pude solucionar de la siguiente manera:

```
public function agregarBolsasModel($datos, $tabla){
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar() -> prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla(lote, caja, bolsa)VALUES(:uno1, :dos2, :tres3)");
        for($p=0; $p<count($datos["valoresBox"]); $p++){
            $stmt -> bindParam(":uno1", $datos["loteNum"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt -> bindParam(":dos2", $datos["cajaNum"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt -> bindParam(":tres3", $datos["valoresBox"][$p], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();

        }
        $stmt = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Usa la funcion **count($array)** de PHP para obtener el tamaño de un arreglo:
Cambia

```
for($p=0; $p<sizeof($datosL); $p++)
```

por

```
for($p=0; $p < count($datosL); $p++)
```

quedando asi:

```
public function agregarBolsasModel($datos, $tabla){
        $datosL=array($datos["valoresBox"]);
        for($p=0; $p < count($datosL); $p++){
            $stmt = Conexion::conectar() -> prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla(lote, caja, bolsa)VALUES(:uno1, :dos2, :tres3)");
            $stmt -> bindParam(":uno1", $datos["loteNum"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt -> bindParam(":dos2", $datos["cajaNum"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt -> bindParam(":tres3", $datosL[$p], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();
        }

          $stmt->close();
 }
```